# SubCategory Carousel arrow for mobile not functioning

Tags: ios, mobile, carousel, arrows

Turned the arrows on for mobile use of the subcategory carousal. The arrows
don't work though when viewing staging on your phone if its an iOS device. You can slide but
when you click the arrows they don't move the images within the slider.It does work when you view it mobile-y on your desktop. 
This is the code:

```html
$(".subCategories").slick({
<? if ($totalSubcategories > 4): ?>
  centerMode: true,
  centerPadding: '15px',
<? endif ?>
  slidesToShow: 4,
  slidesToScroll: 1,
  swipeToSlide: true,
  responsive: [
    {
      breakpoint: 801,
      settings: {
        centerMode: true,
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        swipeToSlide: true
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 500,
      settings: {
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '5px',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        arrows: true,
        swipeToSlide: true
      }
    }
  ]
});
```